# how to add up specific cells in a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum, echo

I have the following mysql table

```
 --------------------------------------------------------
|id  |   hometeam   |goalsfor|goalsagainst|   awayteam   |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |Inter Milan   |   3    |     1      | FC Barcelona |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 2  |FC Barcelona  |   1    |     0      | Inter Milan  |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 3  |Inter Milan   |   4    |     0      | AC Milan     |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 4  |AC Milan      |   0    |     2      | Inter Milan  |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 5  |Real Madrid   |   2    |     0      | AC Milan     |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 6  |AC Milan      |   2    |     2      | Real Madrid  |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 7  |FC Barcelona  |   2    |     2      | AC Milan     |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 8  |Real Madrid   |   2    |     0      | Inter Milan  |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 9  |Inter Milan   |   3    |     1      | Real Madrid  |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 10 |FC Barcelona  |   2    |     0      | Real Madrid  |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 11 |Real Madrid   |   1    |     1      | FC Barcelona |
 --------------------------------------------------------
```

Say I want to add up all the goals that Inter Milan have scored in both home and away games - looking at the table the result should be "12" however from my code I am getting 17,

```
    $query = "SELECT hometeam, SUM(goalsfor), SUM(goalsagainst) FROM fixtures WHERE hometeam='Inter Milan' OR awayteam='Inter Milan'"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $name = $row['hometeam'];
    $f = $row['SUM(goalsfor)'];
    $a = $row['SUM(goalsagainst)'];}
    echo $name; echo $f+$a;

    ?>
```

What would the correct method be so that it will give me the specific result, for example if WHERE hometeam='FC Barcelona' I would like it to echo the result as "7" and so on for the other teams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could also do something like this:

```
SELECT 'Inter Milan', SUM(CASE 
                     WHEN hometeam='Inter Milan' 
                         THEN goalsfor 
                     WHEN awayteam='Inter Milan'
                         THEN goalsagainst 
                 END) as points 
FROM fixtures WHERE hometeam='Inter Milan' OR awayteam='Inter Milan'
```

And avoid the multiple scans. Also using `UNION` will add an implicit `DISTINCT` which could skew your results if you have a game with the same away points as home points in a different game.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

```
SELECT team, SUM(points) FROM (
  SELECT hometeam as team, SUM(goalsfor) as points FROM fixtures WHERE hometeam='Inter Milan'
  UNION 
  SELECT awayteam as team, SUM(goalsagainst) as points FROM fixtures WHERE awayteam='Inter Milan') team_pts
```

Comment: getting an "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: Edited by adding a table alias after the select clause.